# Button tip when Mouse is over

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I have a simple question !
I'd like to know how to add like a tip when the user puts his mouse over a button, like that like grey box that appears right below the button.
I'm using Windows Form !

P.S-> I know it's obsolete and we now have WPF but I'm using Form !

Thanks !

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use [ToolTip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.aspx) on the button. Like.

```
System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip ToolTip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip();
ToolTip1.SetToolTip(this.Button1, "Button Info");
```

Or you can:
Add a ToolTip control to your form, Name it ToolTip1.
 
Add text for tooltip to the "ToolTip on ToolTip1" property of the button.

Comment: @Asif I had to wait the 6 min. Done !